# Best Dual Boot Setup

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

My professor told me that partitioning hard drive is not recommended. It is better to have two separate drives, especially for dual boot system. Now, I will have one SSD and one HDD in my laptop. Which is better?

1. Install Linux and windows in SSD (partitioned) then data drive for HDD or...
2. Install ubuntu in SSD. Install windows in HD, partitioned with data.

and why?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/564308

Answer (score 1):

Well I would actually install and dual boot both off your SSD and use your HDD for storage.
Reason? SSD is much faster, and you will notice the difference when your OS is on it.

Using two hard drives, one OS each may be a little easier to do, but I would recommend your first option for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSD is 64GB or larger I would install both OSs on it. During the Ubuntu install on the partitioning page you can use the other option to set up the HD as your home folder. Make sure to format it as FAT32 or NTFS (depending on whether your version of Ubuntu supports writing to NTFS) so that Windows can read it. Both OSs will benefit from the speed increase of the SSD and the space of the HD and your files will be available to both OSs.

I can confirm that this works in 12.04, but when I tried it the mount settings were executable for all files, which means that you will need to change the default mount options.